# Python can't see Exceptions in module

Tags: python, exception

I use this chunk of code pretty ofthen

```
except Error,e:
    print str(e)
```

However, when I splited my one-file-code into main body and objects, python stops with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "<string>", line 142, in <module>
   File "<string>", line 137, in main
   File "<string>", line 125, in process
   File "/Users/casy/Dropbox/My_Projects/personal_turk/code/misc/settings.py", line 17, in fileReader
   result = ask('path_to_file,please', readCSV,'file read successfully!','something with the filePath')
   File "/Users/casy/Dropbox/My_Projects/personal_turk/code/misc/ask.py", line 33, in ask
   except Error,e:
       NameError: global name 'Error' is not defined
```

So how shall I handle this? Whats wrong?

Comment: Have you defined `Error` anywhere in your code? Or do you mean to use `Exception` instead?

Comment: `Error` isn't a built-in... are you confusing it with `Exception`? Also - that syntax has been deprecated - it's best to use `except Exception as e`...

Answer (score 1):

thats worked for me:

```
except Exception as e
```

thank you, guys!
Strange it still worked in whole code at first!

Answer (score 0):

```
except error as e
```

Also, can you give your full code, I would had commented but can't yet.